# Pandas: How to use apply to create new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I discovered a strange behavior in Python Pandas and wanted to ask if it is my fault or if it is an actual program bug.
Let's take the following DataFrame:

```
data = DataFrame({'k2':[1, 2, 3, ], 'name':['joe', 'mark', 'carl']})
data.set_index('name', drop=False, inplace=True)
```

If I create a function which returns a Series object like that

```
def my_test(i, x):
     x['interrel'] = x.apply(lambda row: i['k2'] - row['k2'] if i['name'] != row['name'] else 0, axis=1)
     print x['interrel'] 
     return x['interrel']
```

and appy that function using apply to the created DataFrame using

```
  data.apply(lambda row: my_test(row, data), axis=1)
```

all I get in the output is the last calculated row times three. However, the print statement in the my_test function shows that the calculations are correct. It seems that only the particular series objects are not appended correctly.

Can you reconstruct this problem? Did I get anything wrong regarding the use of the apply function?

Please consider that this is only an example, I am not asking for another way to do pairwise differences in Pandas

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Well you're passing the df as the second param so the final result will be the last operation

Comment: Thanks, you are right if I do data.copy() it works flawlessly. Could you please elaborate on your answer a little bit more as a dedicated answer, because I did not understand why this last row is broadcasted on each row

Answer (score 1):

Because you're passing your `data` df as a reference and assigning directly to it each time by calling `apply` in your func then it overwrites with the last operation:

```
In [20]:

def my_test(i, x):
    x['interrel'] = x.apply(lambda row: i['k2'] - row['k2'] if i['name'] != row['name'] else 0, axis=1)
    #print(x['interrel'])
    print("x-----",x, "\n-------")
    return x['interrel']
data.apply(lambda row: my_test(row, data), axis=1)
x-----       k2  name  interrel
name                    
joe    1   joe         0
mark   2  mark        -1
carl   3  carl        -2 
-------
x-----       k2  name  interrel
name                    
joe    1   joe         0
mark   2  mark        -1
carl   3  carl        -2 
-------
x-----       k2  name  interrel
name                    
joe    1   joe         1
mark   2  mark         0
carl   3  carl        -1 
-------
x-----       k2  name  interrel
name                    
joe    1   joe         2
mark   2  mark         1
carl   3  carl         0 
-------
Out[20]:
name  joe  mark  carl
name                 
joe     2     1     0
mark    2     1     0
carl    2     1     0
```

As you've found if you pass a copy of your data then the operations are performed on the copy of the original data and the correct result is returned, you can see that the `data` df is unaffected:

```
 In [22]:

def my_test(i, x):
    x['interrel'] = x.apply(lambda row: i['k2'] - row['k2'] if i['name'] != row['name'] else 0, axis=1)
    #print(x['interrel'])
    print("x-----",x, "\n-------")
    return x['interrel']
print(data.apply(lambda row: my_test(row, data.copy()), axis=1))
print(data)
x-----       k2  name  interrel
name                    
joe    1   joe         0
mark   2  mark        -1
carl   3  carl        -2 
-------
x-----       k2  name  interrel
name                    
joe    1   joe         0
mark   2  mark        -1
carl   3  carl        -2 
-------
x-----       k2  name  interrel
name                    
joe    1   joe         1
mark   2  mark         0
carl   3  carl        -1 
-------
x-----       k2  name  interrel
name                    
joe    1   joe         2
mark   2  mark         1
carl   3  carl         0 
-------
name  joe  mark  carl
name                 
joe     0    -1    -2
mark    1     0    -1
carl    2     1     0
      k2  name  interrel
name                    
joe    1   joe         2
mark   2  mark         1
carl   3  carl         0
```